# Set the scope based on parent resource while using concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am curious, is there any way to set the scope for nested resources based on parent resource while using concerns in Rails?

```
concern :commentable do
  scope module: ??? do # either :posts or :messages
    resources :comments
  end
end

resources :messages, concerns: :commentable
resources :posts, concerns: :commentable
```

I want my routes to be like these:

```
Path                                  Controller
/messages/:message_id/comments/:id    messages/comments#show
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id          posts/comments#show
```

but I also want to use concerns in order to reduce duplication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out method `concerns` can take a hash of options.

```
concern :commentable do |options|
  scope module: options[:module] do
    resources :comments
  end
end

resources :messages do 
  concerns :commentable, module: :messages
end

resources :posts do 
  concerns :commentable, module: :posts
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I started with your solution using an options hash but it turns out I really need this pattern a lot so I worked out another solution for that specific case :

```ruby
concern :archivable do
  scope module: parent_resource.plural do
    resources :archiving, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end    
end

...
resources :messages , concerns: [ :archivable ]
resources :users , concerns: [ :archivable ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rails Polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to fit this situation where a `comment` can `belong_to` any other model as well...`post`,`video`,`user` etc

Wonderful [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).....which is worth watching.

Comment: sorry, this is not what I wanted exactly. maybe the question was not clear enough. any way, I solved the problem using `options` param.